# Encode function data with value

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, abi, abi.encodewithsignature

I have Contract A:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol";

contract A {

using Address for address payable;

 function proxyCallWithValue(address payable target, bytes memory callData, uint256 value)
 external
 payable {
     target.functionCallWithValue(callData, value);
 }
}
```

And contract B:

```
contract B {

    function test(uint256 tokenId)
    external
    payable {
     //doing something..
    }
  }
```

And I would like to have contract A calling B with value.

With no value I would go;

```
const aABI = getContractABI('A')
const bABI = getContractABI('B')
const bInterface = new ethers.utils.Interface(bABI)
const tokenId = 1234
const value = 1000000
const callData = bInterface.encodeFunctionData("test", [tokeiId])

const contractA = ethers.Contract(aAddress, aABI, provider)

// calling contract A (which should call bontract B)
await contractA.proxyCallWithValue(bAddress, callData, value)
```

How do I also send value from the calling wallet to contract A when calling method `proxyCallWithValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to send along ETH with your call when you talk about "sending value". You can specify this on the call with `{value: 1000000 }`.

This is specified in the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/control-structures.html#external-function-calls).

> When calling functions of other contracts, you can specify the amount of Wei or gas sent with the call with the special options `{value: 10, gas: 10000}`.

You can also read the value sent along in a call with `msg.value`.